# VSCode: Find & Replace using regex and keep surrounding context (uncaptured portions)

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I replace a word, I often like to specify context surrounding that work to exclude false positives. I do this with regular expressions in VSCode. For example:

```
Find:     (packagereference.*")unity(")
Replace:  $1Autofac$2
```

I personally find it tedious to have to specify the beginning and end surrounding context to avoid losing it when it is replaced. It would be nicer to "invert" this so that only the captured portions of the search query are replaced, while the parts not captured are kept. For example:

```
Find:     packagereference.*"(unity)"
Replace:  Autofac
```

Which, for example, would yield the following change:

```
Before:  <PackageReference Include="Unity" />
After:   <PackageReference Include="Autofac" />
```

I imagine the answer is "No, can't do it that way", but I don't know that for certain. Is it possible to make find & replace operations like this less tedious from a regular expression syntax perspective?

Comment: have you tried positive lookbehind and lookahead, but the lookbehind has to be fixed length in some regex engines

Comment: In the case of VSCode, [it appears this isn't possible](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76502). I used this as a test: `(?<=packagereference.*")unity(?=")` and I get an error about how the lookbehind must be fixed length :(

Comment: For the search across files, the lookbehind must be of fixed length, but not when using the find widget for the current file.

Comment: Of course, `(?<=packagereference Include=")unity(?=")` works just fine.  Is there something other than `Include=` that could appear there?

Comment: @Mark, No just being lazy. But it's a valid solution. Thank you.